# Opencart cart page error in localhost

Tags: php, opencart

Can someone help me on this simple problem?
I have using opencart and hosted it in GoDaddy. I created development server so that I could test the design and functions before I upload it to live. But this made me crazy because everything is working fine when I upload the live site to development server. But when I create a test order, I got an error in checkout/cart which says ***"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\cart.tpl on line 308"***

I am so confused because the cart.tpl is working on the live site and that error showed on the development server. I don't have any idea why it is happening.

Info:
I am using XAMPP as my php server
I am using Opencart v1.5.6.4 on the development server while v.1.5.5.1 on the live site. Is there any problem with it? Hope you guys throw some help.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Post the contents of C:\xampp\htdocs\catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\cart.tpl  lines 300 to 320

Comment: You forget to close `}`.

Comment: why the magento tag?

Comment: @Debflav, I did not modify nor change the cart template from live so I think close tag } is not the cause of this error.

Comment: @OSdave, oh sorry, I forgot to remove the magento tag on my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning this error you have few unclosed braces `}`.

The error occured at line 60:

```
<?php if (!$product['stock']) { ?>
<div class="list_produ_name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><font color="red"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></font></a><?php $product['custID']; ?>
<? } else { ?>
<div class="list_produ_name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a><?php $product['custID']; ?>
<? } ?>
```

I guess it's not working because you are using php short open tag tag "`<?`" and `short_open_tag`are disabled by default.
So the solution is to change the "`<?`" to "`<?php`"

```
<?php if (!$product['stock']) { ?>
<div class="list_produ_name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><font color="red"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></font></a><?php $product['custID']; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="list_produ_name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a><?php $product['custID']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is now working. :) Yesterday I read about the difference between <? and <?php and I'm about to modify those php short tags. anyway, thank you! great!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put closing braces}, Better you post your code. Also, you can see by changing the PHP tag weather problem solve or not

Comment: Hello guys,
here is the link of the cart.tpl

http://pastebin.com/2Dk6wbtd

thanks in advance!!! :)